# Data from multi <td>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

How can I select data from this?

```
<tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <td class="drop" name="mon-1">
       <td class="item assigned"> -- DATA --</td>
    </td>
    <td class="drop" name="mon-2"></td>
    <td class="drop" name="mon-3"></td>
</tr>
```

I need some as **select data from mon-1** as **string**.

I send all with POST method.

```
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('.subjects .item').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone'
            });
            $('.timetable td.drop').droppable({
                onDrop: function(e,source) {
                    if ($(source).hasClass('assigned')){
                        $(this).append(source);
                    } else {
                        var c = $(source).clone().addClass('assigned');
                        $(this).empty().append(c);
                        c.draggable({
                            revert:true
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            $('.subjects').droppable({
                accept:'.assigned',

                onDragEnter: function(e, source){
                    $(source).addClass('delete');
                },
                onDragLeave: function(e, source){
                    $(source).removeClass('delete');
                },
                onDrop: function(e, source){
                    $(source).remove();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

<table>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        foreach($subjects as $subject) {
                    ?>
                        <td class="item">
                            <?php echo($subject["name"]); ?>
                        </td>   
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

So I drag and drop some .item to some .drop.

And I need send to database data from .drop .

So I need select mon-1 and load data from , which is inside.

Comment: You can't nest `<td>` inside `<td>` like that. `<td>` has to be a child of `<tr>`

Comment: There's no PHP in the question, I removed the irrelevant tag. If the question really is about PHP, you need to clarify it.

Comment: I am sorry, I dunno how you think it. Can you post some example? Adding some <tr> or <td> is last choice, because I have static design, so I don't want to change it.

Comment: Each `<td>` is a cell in the table, what do you expect to happen by having a cell inside a cell?

Comment: If you show how this is supposed to be rendered, we can try to help you code it properly.

Comment: Your question is also unclear. What do you mean by "select data from this"? HTML tables just display data, where are you trying to select it?

Comment: Are you writing a web scraper?

Comment: I drop another <td> to <td> with draggable and droppable in jQuery. But I can't determine, if user drop <td> to monday or thusday .. and which number (it is probably possible, but hardly then this). So I drag <td> and drop it to <td>. I need select <td> with name like mon-1 or some other and select data from <td> inside. I try select it with $_POST on another page.

Comment: Maybe you should be dragging a `<span>` instead of a `<td> and leave the `<td>` where it is. Or when you drop it, it should be inserted between the other `<td>`, not inside.

Comment: I need use <td>.

Comment: `$_POST` gets its data from `<input>` elements, not `<td>`

Comment: You need to use valid HTML. Browsers will do unpredictable things if you try to create invalid DOM relationships.

Comment: Look up pls, I sent my code.